# Display options for react-bootstrap-typeahead when using apolloconsumer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to display a list of options retrieved from a graphql query in react-bootstrap-typeahead.
I can see this.state.options is updating and my component is re-rendering so I see the new values in the console log.  But I keep getting 'No matches found' in my typeahead dropdown.

My react component render method:

```
render() {
    console.log('rendering', this.state.options);

    return (
        <ApolloConsumer>
            { client => (
                <AsyncTypeahead
                    {...this.state}
                    labelKey="value"
                    minLength={3}
                    onSearch={e => this.handleSearch(e, client)}
                    placeholder="Search for options..."
                    renderMenuItemChildren={option => (
                        <LookupItem key={option.id} option={option} />
                    )}
                />
            )}
        </ApolloConsumer>
    );
}
```

My handleSearch method:

```
async handleSearch(searchValue, client) {
    this.setState(state => ({
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
    }));
    const { data, error } = await client.query({
        query: LookupQuery,
        variables: {
            lookupValue: searchValue,
            limit: 10,
        },
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    });
    if (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    } else {
        const lookupValues = _.get(data, 'lookup', []);
        this.setState(state => ({
            ...state,
            isLoading: false,
            options: lookupValues.map(item => ({ value: item.value, description: item.description })),
        }));
    }
}
```

LookupItem:

```
const LookupItem = ({ option }) => {
    console.log('option', option);
    return (
        <div>
            <span>{option.value}</span>
        </div>
    );
};
```

I hope that all makes sense.  Thanks in advance - and apologies if this is something incredibly stupid!

Comment: Can you post a link to a jsfiddle or codepen that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: Your `renderMenuItemChildren` function looks suspicious. You're producing an empty `<LookupItem>` using `option.id`, but you don't assign `id` to the options in `handleSearch`.

Comment: Hint: Make sure that what your are typing matches the start of the results you are setting within the setState({ ... options: )}. This is because there is a client side filter that removes any options value that do not match what has been entered in the input field. I was returning mock data and realized that it was always filtering the data out until I typed the right text